Hanging chair from roof truss causing flex
I located a joist to mount my daughter’s hammock chair from. The install went as planned and I hit joist. The issue is there doesn’t seem to be a support preventing the cross beam from flexing. This is resulting in the joist flexing and drywall bowing when load is applied to the chair.
Is there something I can do from below to address this?
My thought was to open up the drywall enough to add a metal plate on either side of the framing to add rigidity, but I figured being a novice I’d ask the pros what they would do.



Those trusses are made mainly to hold drywall and a bit of a person walking on them the odd times.  A moving/swinging weight will put stress on them, so flexing is expected.

Thoughts on alternative options for me?

More related questions

FYI, "metal plates" aren't the cure-all many folks seem to think. Firstly, the stress isn't just right at the anchor point. Secondly, a plate is only rigid on one axis. Don't even get me started on angle brackets.

I voted to close as this is essentially like all the other chair-from-ceiling questions on this site. The general solution presented in How to hang a chair from the ceiling joists (with attic access) is appropriate. However, yours does have one unique quality: Your chosen hang location is about as ideal as they come short of being under a primary support beam.
Because you're at the right-angle intersection of the hip trusses you potentially have solid two-axis stability, if you bolster the connections. You'd have to add building hardware or suitable bolts through that connection to lock it together. It's likely connected by just a couple nails now.
Then, you'd have to run a spreader across that intersection and out to at least two adjacent points. 2x4 ceiling joists (truss bottom chords) are sized to carry ceiling drywall and insulation, not several hundred lbs. of dynamic load. This is especially true since you're mid-span between gusset nodes.
Bottom line: Add substantial framing support or just don't.
